# Android tablet where WhatsApp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, tablet

My iPad has 4G but you cannot call with it so you cannot keep WhatsApp there. I am thinknig to if there is any Android tablet where you can keep WhatsApp.

Comment: My Samsung Note 10.1 (GT-N8000) has WhatsApp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WhatsApp is not compatible with tablets on Android. You could try using https://web.whatsapp.com/ through the web browser on an android tablet.

Comment: The latter does not work if you do not keep smartphone active.

Comment: It works  on my tablet(Samsung GT-N8000)